# Fatal error while connecting to Excel workbook

Tags: php, excel

While running the code which is used to connect to the workbook I get fatal error.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$filename = "C:/Users/.../Output.xlsb";
$sheet1 = "DAILY_OUTPUT";
$sheet2 = "DAILY_OUTPUT";
$excel_app = new COM("Excel.application") or Die ("Did not connect");
$Workbook = $excel_app->Workbooks->Open("$filename") or Die("Did not open $filename $Workbook");
$Worksheet = $Workbook->Worksheets($sheet1);
$Worksheet->activate;
$excel_cell = $Worksheet->Range("C4");
$excel_cell->activate;
$excel_result = $excel_cell->value;
print "$excel_result\n";
$Worksheet = $Workbook->Worksheets($sheet2);
$Worksheet->activate;
$excel_cell = $Worksheet->Range("C4");
$excel_cell->activate;
$excel_result = $excel_cell->value;
print "$excel_result\n";
#To close all instances of excel:
$Workbook->Close;
unset($Worksheet);
unset($Workbook);
$excel_app->Workbooks->Close();
$excel_app->Quit();
unset($excel_app);
```

And when I run it from PhpStorm to Google Chrome it shows:

```
Fatal error: in C:\Users\...\excCon.php on line 6
```

*Edit: the "..." are just to shorten the URL here*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was wrong slashes.
Instead of single `/` I put double `\` and now the path to the file is correctly read.